# How to import v4 animations classes?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-support-library

After update support libraries I got this error:
[image]

`Cannot resolve symbol ValueAnimatorCompat`

This is my gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

How to import animations classes?

P.S. I add google maven repository to gradle file.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך no, I make all steps from your varinat